# Listview Checkbox - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, checkbox

Ok, i have a listview with checkboxes and a button, how it works is that i have to check the items i want to change the values, then press the button to change the value of those checked item, here's my code on the button.

```
     Try
        Dim I As Integer
        If lv_id.CheckedItems.Count = 0 Then
            For I = 0 To lv_id.Items.Count - 1
                lv_id.Items(I).SubItems(1).Text = "Pending"
            Next
        Else
            For I = 0 To lv_id.CheckedItems.Count - 1
                lv_id.CheckedItems(I).SubItems(1).Text = "Submitted"
            Next
        End If
        Proc_Items.BackColor = Color.Green
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Now, what i want to do is, to remove the button and then when i'll check the item i want to the code above will do the process without pressing the button, i tried "ItemCheck, ItemChecked" event, but with no luck.

Comment: What problem did you have with the ItemChecked event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the ItemChecked event for this. With the ItemCheckedEventArgs giving you everything you need.

This example would set up to toggle the 3rd column depending on the checkbox state

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemChecked(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemChecked
    If e.Item.Checked Then
        e.Item.SubItems(2).Text = "Submitted"
    Else
        e.Item.SubItems(2).Text = "Pending"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you want to run your code whenever a ckecbox in your ListView gets checked or unchecked. This can be done using

```
Public Class Form1
    'The ListView_SelectedIndexChanged event triggers when a checkbox of the listview gets checked or unchecked
    Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
        'Put your code here, access all checked items with "ListBox1.CheckedItems"
    End Sub
End Class
```

This worked for me, and I think it works for you as well. If not, please tell me in the comments what went wrong.